# Finding a missing value in an inconsistent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am not really sure where to even start with this problem.
I am given a matrix with 1 missing value in the coefficient matrix. I am also told it is inconsistent, which as I understand means there are no solutions or a row could look like:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 0 &| 1\\
  \end{array}$$
This is the matrix that I am given:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
   2 & h &| 4\\
   3 & 6 &| 7\\
  \end{array}$$

I tried to reduce the matrix first by:

$$R2 \leftarrow R1(-3) + R2(2)$$
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
    2 & h &| 4\\
    0 & 12-3h &| 2\\
   \end{array}$$

Not sure if I am on the right track or not, but I just don't know where to go from here.

I know that there are similar questions to this one on this forum, but I just don't understand the solutions, and the question matrices are a bit more complicated. So, I apologize up front for the repeat, I just need an "Explain to me like I'm 5".

Thank you for a quick response, and not just answering my problem for me. For those of you reading this with a similar question. First thank you to Anurag A!

If this is not the proper answer please feel free to correct it or let me know how I went wrong.

After reducing the augmented matrix we have:
$$R2 = 0x + (12-3h)y = 2$$

In order to solve we must find where $12-3h=0$
meaning $h=4$

or 
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
   2 & 4 &| 4\\
   3 & 6 &| 7\\
  \end{array}$$

Hopefully, that is right!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So for inconsistency you need the left hand side to be $0$ and the RHS to be none-zero. That means $12-3h=0$ and RHS is already $2$ which is non-zero.

Comment: I apologize, I guess i still don't understand. So h is any number which makes the linear equation $12-3h$ equal to 0? So, in that case the answer would have to be 4?

Comment: Just reread you question a little harder, that is exactly what you are saying. Sorry again, I joined a summer Applied Matrix Theory summer class a week late and so I am having to teach myself the first section of the book and do the first two homework assignments before monday! So after 2 days of non-stop reading and googling I am a bit brain dead. I havent looked at a matrix since 9th grade algebra which was 11 years ago!

Comment: Put differently, $3x+6y=7$ is equivalent to (multiply both sides by $\frac23$) $2x+4y=\frac{14}3$. The only way to get an inconsistency is to have an equation (equivalent to) $2x+4y=\text(someting else)$. The equation you can play with reads $2x+hy=4$. The only choice for $h$ to make $2x+hy=4$ look like $2x+4y=\text(someting else)$ is ...